# "ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence." when scaling multiple columns

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, lstm

I am messing around with time series forecasting and when i am scaling the data i am receiving the follwing error:

> line 86, in 
> scaler, train_scaled, test_scaled = scale(train, test)
> line 37, in scale
> scaler = scaler.fit(train)
> ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

My code works fine when I am scaling two columns of data but when i try to add a third column it stops working.
My data: https://i.stack.imgur.com/H47NO.png

And this is my code:

```
def timeseries_to_supervised(data, lag=1):
    df = DataFrame(data)
    columns = [df.shift(i) for i in range(1, lag+1)]
    columns.append(df)
    df = concat(columns, axis=1)
    df.fillna(0, inplace=True)
    return df

def difference(dataset, interval=1):
    diff = list()
    for i in range(interval, len(dataset)):
        value = dataset[i] - dataset[i - interval]
        diff.append(value)
    return Series(diff)  

def scale(train, test):
        scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(-1, 1))
        scaler = scaler.fit(train)
        
        train = train.reshape(train.shape[0], train.shape[1])
        train_scaled = scaler.transform(train)
    
        test = test.reshape(test.shape[0], test.shape[1])
        test_scaled = scaler.transform(test)
    
        return scaler, train_scaled, test_scale

series = pd.read_excel('amx.xlsx', header=0, parse_dates=[0], index_col=0, squeeze=True)

raw_values = series.values
diff_values = difference(raw_values, 1)

supervised = timeseries_to_supervised(diff_values, 1)
supervised_values = supervised.values

train, test = supervised_values[0:-4], supervised_values[-4:]

scaler, train_scaled, test_scaled = scale(train, test)
```

Comment: Can you print your supervised_values?

Comment: @HakanAkgün Yes, this is the output, [[0 array([11.  , -0.11])]
 [array([11.  , -0.11]) array([-186.  ,   -0.29])]
 [array([-186.  ,   -0.29]) array([-9.5e+01, -2.0e-02])]
 [array([-9.5e+01, -2.0e-02]) array([8.3e+01, 8.0e-02])]
 [array([8.3e+01, 8.0e-02]) array([-16.  ,  -0.06])]
 [array([-16.  ,  -0.06]) array([-1.72e+02, -1.50e-01])]
 [array([-1.72e+02, -1.50e-01]) array([48.  ,  0.08])]
 [array([48.  ,  0.08]) array([ 1.65e+02, -1.60e-01])]
 [array([ 1.65e+02, -1.60e-01]) array([-2.45e+02, -4.00e-02])]
 [array([-2.45e+02, -4.00e-02]) array([57.  ,  0.45])]

Comment: Can you also sent it for your 3 dimensional updated data?

Comment: @HakanAkgün I am not quite sure what you mean, currently I am reshaping the data to 3 dimensions in this method: def fit_lstm(train, batch_size, nb_epoch, neurons):
    X, y = train[:, 0:-1], train[:, -1]
    X = X.reshape(X.shape[0], 1, X.shape[1]) but that is supposed to use the scaled train data which I am unable to get at the moment.

Comment: Can you make this error reproducible in google collab? It's hard to see where is the problem.

Comment: @HakanAkgün Here is the link to google collab, i couldn't upload the excel file but it is just the data that i put in the original post. https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1EzGchHt2y2HEbz65F9WiLcSi_zTUFIle?usp=sharing

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems you've not uploaded sample data so the error is no reproducible.